# Проблема при реализации stl совместимого forward_iterator'а

Tags: c++, stl, итераторы

Я новичок в C++ и в качестве учебного задания разрабатываю свой собственный HashMap, однако, при реализации forward iterator'а столкнулся с проблемой, при которой некоторые алгоритмы STL (например, std::find_if и std::find_if_not) не работают и анализатор выдает следующую ошибку:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:162:10: error: no matching function for call to '__iterator_category' [clang-diagnostic-error]
                   std::__iterator_category(__first));
```

Когда делал через наследование (`class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, V>`), то всё работало исправно и никаких проблем не возникало, но преподаватель сказал, что этот способ устаревший и сейчас так делать не надо. В интернете видел способ с явным указанием member types от std::iterator, но когда я пытаюсь это сделать, то получаю ошибку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Как мне правильно создать stl совместимый forward iterator для моего класса в современном C++?
Структура моего итератора такова:

```
class Iterator {
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef V value_type;
    typedef HashNode* pointer;
    typedef HashNode& reference;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    friend HashMap;`

   private:
    Iterator(pointer* table, size_t index, pointer node)
        : table_(table), index_(index), node_(node) { ... }
    Iterator(pointer* table, size_t index) : table_(table), index_(index) { ... }`

    pointer* table_;
    size_t index_;
    pointer node_;

   public:
    K key() const { ... }
    Iterator& operator++() { ... }
    Iterator operator++(int) { ... }
    bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const { ... }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { ... }
    const value_type& operator*() const { ... }
    value_type& operator*() { ... }
  };
```

(Где V - это тип значения узла, K - тип ключа узла. Эти типы описаны в шаблоне основного класса Hashmap. HashNode - тип узла HashMap).

Comment: *"преподаватель сказал, что этот способ устаревший и сейчас так делать не надо"* Хороший у вас препод.

Answer (score 1):

> `std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;`

Неправильно. Правильно так: `using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;` (или `typedef`, что то же самое).

Также заметьте, что в C++20 эти тайпдефы больше не обязательны, и угадываются автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена переносом всех параметров в область public. Вот рабочий вариант:

```
class Iterator {
    friend HashMap;

   private:
    Iterator(pointer* table, size_t index, pointer node)
        : table_(table), index_(index), node_(node) { ... }
    Iterator(pointer* table, size_t index) : table_(table), index_(index) { ... }`

    pointer* table_;
    size_t index_;
    pointer node_;

   public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = V;
    using pointer = HashNode*;
    using reference = HashNode&;
    using size_type = size_t;

    K key() const { ... }
    Iterator& operator++() { ... }
    Iterator operator++(int) { ... }
    bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const { ... }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const { ... }
    const value_type& operator*() const { ... }
    value_type& operator*() { ... }
  };
```